# complex integration with elementary fuctions help

Tags: complex-integration

I needed some help on how to solve this problem.

Integrate $$\oint_C \frac{\sin z}{4z^2-8iz}dz $$
where $C$ consists of boundaries of the squares with vertices $\pm3,\pm3i$ counterclockwise and $\pm1,\pm i$ clockwise.

My approach was like,

$$\oint_C \frac{\sin z}{4z(z-2i)}$$
$$= \oint_C \frac{\frac{\sin z}{4z}}{z-2i}$$

So if $\frac{\sin z}{4z}$ in analytic on C, then we can use Cauchy's Integral Formula.

But, how can I check whether $\frac{\sin z}{4z}$ is analytic or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\sin z$ has a root at $z=0$ and is analytic, it follows that $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is also analytic.

More concretely, it is given by the series
$$
\frac{\sin z}{z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
and is therefore analytic. Since $\sin z$ is entire, we also see that $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is entire (the sum converges absolutely for all $z\in \mathbb C$).

Comment: So as it's analytic, the answer for the integration will be pi/4 * sin(2i) ? using Cauchy's integral theorem.